# Deleting resources from two different tables in one RESTful API request

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, restful-url

In my RESTful API I need to have two operations:

1. Remove player
2. Remove player and his/her games

Although the first operation is obvious (DELETE request with URL */api/players/playerId*), the second operation got me thinking.

Second operation is tricky. You can remove the player and leave the game in the system but also there is an option that the player will delete all games he was in. As weird as it sounds, please believe me. I'm really curious how well designed API should handle such situation.

Is it a good practice to have a DELETE request with an bool option "removeGames". For example:

```
DELETE /api/players/playerId?removeGames=1
```

Comment: Game is a separate Domain object, therefore I'd have a separate Controller/Route to handle operations dealing with Game.

Comment: I prefer the way you have done, although William is correct as well. I would be hesitant to initiate two different transactions in order to delete games for a player before deleting the player. These are some of the possible options to consider as well:

(1) DELETE /api/players/id -> no games delete

(2) DELETE /api/players/{id}/games/{false} -> no games delete

(3) DELETE /api/players/{id}/games/{true} -> games do get deleted

Comment: @WilliamXifaras I totally understand this and almost agree. The only concern I have is two different db transactions in one logic transaction (even two different requests)

Comment: @fluidguid thanks. In (2) and (3) what is {false} and {true}? Like literally the string "true" or "1"?

Comment: I think it can be true or false. Deserialization of Json will automatically convert string "true/false" to bool object too. Easy to read too.

Comment: Found a link that suggests similar idea:  
https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/#delete

Comment: @fluidguid thanks for the link, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like this idea of passing bools to delete other domain objects.
I would do something along these lines:

1. DELETE to /api/players/playerId
2. DELETE to /api/players/playerId/games if you want to delete all of them
3. DELETE to /api/players/playerId/games/gameId for a specific game

Of course you will have to make a decision what happens when you delete the player but keep the games, or you try to delete a game from a player that is already deleted